# Fetching latest data from Rx Maybe when Rx Observable changes

Tags: rx-java

I have a use case where I want to combine data from an `Observable<M>` with the latest value from a `Maybe<N>`. The API with the `Maybe` is an external API which I don't have control over. Effectively what I want to do is lazily fetch the value from the `Maybe` when the `Observable` changes and combine them using a function.

For simplicity, let's assume `M` is `Integer` and `N` is `String`. I tried writing the following:

```
public interface SomeExternalApi {
  Maybe<String> getLatestString();
}

public interface SomeInternalApi {
  Observable<Integer> getIntegerObservable();
}

public class MyClass {

  private final SomeExternalApi externalApi;
  private final SomeInternalApi internalApi;

  public Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super IntegerAndString> observer) {
    return internalApi
        .getIntegerObservable()
        .withLatestFrom(
            externalApi.getLatestString().toObservable(),
            integerData, stringData -> new IntegerAndString(integerData, stringData)
        .subscribe(observer); 
  }

  private static class IntegerAndString {
    // data class that holds onto both
  } 
}
```

The problem here, I think, is that the `Observable` generated by `externalApi.getLatestString()` is just frozen with whatever the value was when it was called. Thus, it keeps sending in `IntegerAndString` whatever the original value returned from the `Maybe<String>` was.

Is there a way to write an `Observable` that lazily fetches its data from the `Maybe` when called or some other pattern I can use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Maybe<T>` by definition emits a maximum of one element.

I think you basically want to call `externalApi.getLatestString()` repeatedly. I haven't tested this, but you can try using `Observable.defer(...)` here:

```
      public Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super IntegerAndString> observer) {
        return internalApi
            .getIntegerObservable()
            .withLatestFrom( Observable.defer(
                () -> externalApi.getLatestString().toObservable() ),
                integerData, stringData -> new IntegerAndString(integerData, stringData)
            .subscribe(observer));
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution!